# Selecting part of image on windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, picturebox

I'm making instrument to select part of image. I have PictrureBox, and simple way to make it :

```
void StartPanel(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    xStart = args.X;
    yStart = args.Y;
    panelStarted = true;
    pan.Location = new Point(xStart, yStart);
}
void FinishPanel(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    xFinish = args.X;
    yFinish = args.Y;
    panelStarted = false;
}

void UpdatePanel(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    if (panelStarted)
    {
        int x = args.X;
        int y = args.Y;

        int newxstart = xStart;
        int newystart = yStart;
        int neww = 0;
        int newh = 0;

        if (x >= xStart)
            neww = x - xStart;
        else
        {
            neww = xStart - x;
            newxstart = x;
        }
        if (y >= yStart)
            newh = y - yStart;
        else
        {
            newh = yStart - y;
            newystart = y;
        }

        pan.Size = new Size(neww, newh);
        pan.Location = new Point(newxstart, newystart);
    }
}
```

When I move mouse right and down, it is absolutely ok. But when I move it left or up I can see blinks at my area. So I have understood, that it is because when I move mouse left or up, my panel is redrawed, because Panel.Location is changed, and when I move mouse right and down, location is not changed, only size is changed, so it is not redrawed, just some pixels are added to panel. What is standart solution for this?

Comment: The standard solution is to use e.Graphics.FillRectangle() instead of using a Panel control in the Paint event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy trying to see what you are trying to do, but I guess you are using a panel as a draggable control to drag over the picturebox surface capturing the portion of image below (like a lens) - yes?

If so, then this is not the best way to do it. It is better to just draw a rectangle on the picturebox surface and "drag" that around - this is simple with just using the mouse events to sets the top left corner and use the onpaint to draw the unfilled rectangle over the image. Capturing the image when you are ready is simple too using whatever event you wish, then copy the image giving the same positions to the new bitmap.

Putting one control over another often causes flickers - even with double buffering. It also takes far more code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are describing a drawing issue when resizing the panel, probably the easiest fix is to replace the panel you are using with one that is double buffered and will invalidate on resize a event:

```
public class BufferedPanel : Panel {
  public BufferedPanel() {
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.ResizeRedraw = true;
  }
}
```